# run assoc command without launching cmd.exe

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to find file associations before attempting to launch the file, the best way I could come up to find that association was using the assoc command, my question is can I run this command through some API way?  Right now the application launches a cmd window to run the command and then parse the output.

Comment: Do you *have* to run assoc?  Could you not just let the shell determine how to run the file itself?  I.e. If you ask the shell to execute a .txt file, or a .xlsx, or a .png, it will run the associated program automatically.  That doesn't mean you can't look up the association, but do you need to?

Comment: i need to since if the extension has application associated, i would launch it, or else show the folder in which the file was saved...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/System_File_Association.aspx

Comment: this should,but the documentation says minimum operating system is windows vista, and i am targetting xp and up....

Comment: Where does it say it requires Vista?  All I read in there was that it requires administrative access, "especially under Vista".

Comment: at the end it says

Interface Information
   Minimum operating systems Windows Vista

Answer (score 2):

```
try
{
    Process.Start(@"C:\textfile.txt");
}
catch(Win32Exception e)
{
    Process.Start(@"C:\");
}
```

Works for me.  Starts the associated application (notepad) with the file.  I realize it's not the best way with the exception handling, but it does work.

Comment: Yep, that's what I was getting at. :thumbup: